# Node.js http.createServer how to get error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and am trying to experiment with basic stuff.

My code is this

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Here's the question - how can I see the exceptions thrown (or events thrown) when calling createServer ? I tried try/catch but it doesn't seem to work . In module's API I couldn't find any reference to it . I am asking because I accidentally started a server on a taken port(8888) and the error I got (in command-line) was Error : EDDRINUSE , this is useful enough but it would be nice to be able to understand how errors are caught in node .

Answer (score 37):

You can do this by handling the error event on the server you are creating.  First, get the result of `.createServer()`.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
```

Then, you can easily handle errors:

```
server.on('error', function (e) {
  // Handle your error here
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution as it listens on the right 'server' scope and not the whole process.

Comment: Much better solution.

Comment: Where are the docs for this? I see `'clientError'` but not `'error'` in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror

Comment: @GeoffreyHale `http.Server` extends `net.Server`.  https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error

Comment: this only captures errors emitted by the server ?
but not regular errors thrown by the route handler. Is there something corresponding to errorHandler in express which can also capture sync / async errors by default

Comment: @gaurav5430 Errors in your route and handlers have nothing to do with errors at the HTTP server level.

Comment: yeah, I think I get that, but then how do we enable express like default error handler in http server?

Answer (score 5):

Print stacktrace of uncaught exceptions using following code.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function( err ) {
            console.error(err.stack);
 });
```

Comment: This is a bad approach, you could leak resources like crazy ([>> official statement](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception))

Comment: just add process.exit() here and it will be okay

Answer (score 3):

The error is emitted in the listen() method. The [API documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/) includes an [example](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_listeninglistener) just for your situtation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

To handle uncaught exceptions. Any unhandled exception from the web server could be caught like this.