# Static Web deployment on Node.JS without using any frameworks

Tags: javascript, node.js

On my local machine, I want to deploy static Web pages (containing HTML, CSS, JS files) on Node, without using any framework (e.g., Express). I did put the Web page related files into the public folder, and then call the index.html, by using the fs library in node, as the following:

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./public/index.html', function (err, html) {
  if (err) { throw err;}
  http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(html); response.end();
   }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');;
});
```

I used CURL and all the files (HTML, CSS, JS) are in fact deployed on the localhost. However, when I go to the port 1337 on the localhost, it shows the HTML contents but doesn't show the behavior, written in JS, imported in the index.html.

Comment: You server is set up on port 1337 and not 80. Did you access the correct port?

Comment: Go to http://127.0.0.1:1337

Comment: @Sirko Sorry, did a mistake on the port number, however I still do not get the behavior (written in a JS file in the public directory).

Comment: @ExplosionPills Updated the question. Cutting short, JS still is not responding.

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Node.js http.createServer how to get error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12496491/1169798). Maybe the port is blocked or something similar?

Comment: Is the javascript you are importing from another site (like a CDN) or do you want to deliver it from the same server?  I ask because if you wanted it to be delivered from the same server...your code isn't structured to deliver multiple files but ONLY index.html.

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis you are right, did put the JS in a cloud, and called it from Index.html and it worked. I will appreciate it if you could add your comment as an answer, with why Node does this. I come from Tomcat background, and this behaviour from Node, is really bazaar to me.

Comment: @Sirko No, not the port. See the above two comments.

Comment: ...answer being written now, with a few extra details for future folks finding the question.

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis hehe yes he/she was on the interactions happening in the comment section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index.html file is making a separate request to `index.js` (or whatever the JS file is / files are).  Your server will handle *every* response the same way: serve the contents of the `index.html` file.

Creating a server in this way does not automatically serve files from the file system like other servers such as Apache might.  Instead, you would need to do something like:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  if (request.url == "/index.html" || request.url == "/") {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream("./public/index.html").pipe(response);
  }
  else if (request.url == "/index.js") {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
    fs.createReadStream("./public/index.js").pipe(response);
  }
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Of course writing a route for each file in the file system that you want to serve is probably pretty silly.  You could use a [static file server module](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static), or implement a static file server yourself.  This would involve checking the file system based on the request URL and then serving the file with the correct content type which you can look up [using a module like `mime`](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime).