# Error does not fall into the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, httpserver

I'm using [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server), and expecting that error will fall in the callback:

```
return require('http-server').createServer().httpServer.listen(-1, (e) => {
    console.log(e); // Error is not here
}
```

but it doesn't, and I can get error only in catch:

```
try {
    return require('http-server').createServer().httpServer.listen(-1, (e) => {
        console.log(e); // Error is not here
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e); //Error is here!
    }
}
```

So, how to get an error in callback?

Comment: So what's the problem, you've caught the error?

Comment: The problem is that I want to wrap this function into the Promise like that:
```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    require('http-server').createServer().httpServer.listen(-1, (e) => {
        return reject(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally don't have experience with http-server, but I would expect them to be doing the same as the native http server and return an eventemitter.

See [Node.js http.createServer how to get error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496491/node-js-http-createserver-how-to-get-error)

Answer (score 0):

.listen is listening to all successful traffic on a given port (-1 here), so it's not going to catch errors. You need to create an error event handler like:

```
return (require('http-server').createServer()).on("error", err => {
  return reject (err); // or your own error handling
});
```

Or to be more verbose:

```
let server = require('http-server').createServer();
server.on("error", function (err) {
  return reject(err); // or your own error handling
}
return server;
```

Comment: Okay, but how to wrap it into the Promise? I tried to do this:
`
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    require('http-server').createServer().httpServer.listen(-1, (e) => {
        return reject(e)
    }
}
`

Comment: It seems that `http-server` doesn't has `on` subscribe: `> require('http-server').createServer().on
undefined
`

Comment: Again, I have edited the answer to try to resolve that problem of yours. If that doesn't do it for you, perhaps you need to change `require('http-server')` to `require('http')`.

Comment: No, it didn't, probably it works for native `http-server`, but nor for  this [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server)